For LLM how is the token dictionary built?
For LLM, how was decided how big and how many unique tokens exist for the english language?


For LLM, how was decided how big and how many unique tokens exist for the English language?

Empirically. E.g., see some info from Tokenizer Choice For LLM Training: Negligible or Crucial?:

Analyzing the impact of the vocabulary size revealed that in the monolingual English setting, the
smaller/medium-sized, i.e., a vocabulary size of
33k/50k performs better (Table 5) whereas in the
multilingual setting, in all cases except for German,
larger vocabulary sizes result in better downstream
performance. Taking into account the results presented in Table 3 showing that in the monolingual
English setting, the best-performing tokenizer on
average across all tasks had a vocabulary size of
33k and that the best-performing multilingual tokenizer had a vocabulary size of 100k additionally
supports the observation that for the monolingual
English setting a small vocabulary size is beneficial
and for the multilingual setting a large vocabulary
size is required.
Our findings in Fig. 3 show that increasing the vocabulary
size from 50k to larger vocabulary sizes increases
the computational costs in all cases.




